# How `glmnet` re-scales `penalty.factor` with `Inf` values

Tags: glmnet

I know how `glmnet` re-scales the `penalty.factor` with a sum `nvar` as discussed in this [post](https://statisticaloddsandends.wordpress.com/2018/11/13/a-deep-dive-into-glmnet-penalty-factor/).

$$
\underset{\beta}{\operatorname{minimize}} \frac{1}{2} \frac{\mathrm{RSS}}{n}+\lambda \sum_{j=1}^p \frac{c_j}{\bar{c}}\left(\frac{1-\alpha}{2}\left\|\beta_j\right\|_2^2+\alpha\left\|\beta_j\right\|_1\right)
$$

But when `penalty.factor` take `Inf` values, that is excluding some variables, how the re-scaling works?

Does it re-scale it to a sum to be the number of included variables, say `nvar.included`.

And how could I verify that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received a response from Prof. Trevor Hastie, the author of the `glmnet` package. (Thanks!)

> In the glmnet code, we convert an inf for penalty factor to an exclude (another argument which lists the excluded variables),
> and then internally reset it to 1 (so as to have minimal effect on the rescaling).

The new version will include it into the help file

I confirmed this using `CVXR`, where I constructed an explicit objective function, and found that it matched perfectly. Check the code below

```
library(glmnet)
library(CVXR)

# simulate data
n <- 500
p <- 10
x <- matrix(rnorm(n*p), ncol=p)
b <- c(1:5, rep(0, 5))
y <- x %*% b + rnorm(n, sd = .5)


# fix penalty value
l <- 0.1
pf=c(1:5/10, rep(Inf, 5))  ## exclude last 5 variables

# fit with glmnet
fit_glmnet <- glmnet(x=x, y=y, standardize=FALSE, intercept=TRUE, 
                     penalty.factor=pf)
betas_glmnet <- as.vector(coef(fit_glmnet, s=l, exact=TRUE, x=x, y=y, 
                               penalty.factor=pf))


# fit with CVXR
## for Inf values in penalty.factor
## 1. exclude corresponding x cols
## 2. convert penalty factor into 1
x.index <- c(pf!=Inf)
beta <- Variable(sum(x.index)+1)
pf.new <- pf
pf.new[pf== Inf] <- 1
pf.scale <- pf.new / mean(pf.new)
## pf.scale <- pf[x.index] / mean(pf[x.index]) / sum(x.index) * p
loss <- l * p_norm(pf.scale[x.index]*beta[-1], 1)
obj <- Minimize( sum((y - beta[1] - x[,x.index] %*% beta[-1])^2) / (2*n) + loss)

## solver                
prob <- Problem(obj)
result <- solve(prob, verbose=FALSE)
betas_cvxr <- drop(result$getValue(beta))

## compare results
betas_cvxr <- c(betas_cvxr, rep(0,5))
round(cbind(betas_glmnet, betas_cvxr), 5)
```